# Flower identification

Tags: identification, flowers, wildflowers

I was hoping someone might be able to help me identify this flower please.  I have tried some identification websites, but I've not been able to find anything that matched perfectly.
I don't have many details, but I am happy to get more info or more pics if you need them.
All I can tell you at the moment is that it is flowing in July in South East England (summer) and it is growing as if a weed.

The closest matches I could find from identification sites were Swordleaf inula, or Echinacea 'Cleopatra' but they just don't match exactly.

Please let me know if there are any questions.
thanks

[image: Yellow Flower]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as Strawflower (*[Xerochrysum bracteatum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerochrysum_bracteatum)*). It is a well-known flower for drying and lasts long time. Best cut before opening to full flower if you wish to preserve as a cut flower.

Edit: also known popularly as Helichrysum.

Comment: Thank you @colin-beckingham, it definitely seems to be a Xerochrysum Bracteatum.  I believe it used to be under the Helichrysum family but has been re-classified as a Xerochrysum, from the wikipedia page on Xerochrysum bracteatum that you have linked to.